# How to return a collection of models with selected columns and relation eager loaded in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, eager-loading

**Problem details:**

I have three models

- a `Directorate` with `id` and `name` fields,
- an `Employee` with `id` and `name` fields and
- a `Telephone` with `id`, `tel`, `employee_id`, `directorate_id`, `description` and `type` fields. The `employee_id` may be nullable, that is there are telephones stored in database with `employee_id = null`

The models are related as follows:

- an employee may have many telephones
- a directorate, may have many telephones

  ```
  class Directorate extends Model
  {
      public function telephones()
      {
          return $this->hasMany(Telephone::class);
      }

      public function employees()
      {
          return $this->hasMany(Employee::class);
      }
  }


  class Employee extends Model
  {
      public function telephones()
      {
          return $this->hasMany(Telephone::class);
      }

      public function directorate()
      {
          return $this->belongTo(Directorate::class);
      }
  }


  class Telephone extends Model
  {
      public function employee()
      {
          return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class);
      }

      public function directorate()
      {
          return $this->belongsTo(Directorate::class);
      }
  }
  ```

**Question:**

I want to fetch a Collection of all the `Telephone` models that belong to a specific `Directorate`, that have `employee_id = null` and also having their `directorate` relation eager loaded. In addition, from that resulting collection of Telephone models, I need only some of the models' fields, that is `id`, `tel` and `description`

Tries

What I tried so far was the following:

I created a query scope in the Telephone model:

```
public function scopeHaveNoEmployeeId($query)
{
    return $query->where('telephones.employee_id', '=', null);
}
```

In my controller

```
$myTelephones = Telephone::with('directorate')

                ->haveNoEmployeeId()

                ->where('directorate_id', $directorateId)

                ->get(['id', 'tel', 'description']);
```

However what I am receiving are the requested fields of the filtered models without the relation eager loaded, for instance:

```
[
{
"id": 79,
"tel": "0648136867",
"directorate": null
},
{
"id": 380,
"tel": "0223796011",
"directorate": null
}
]
```

I tried also to lazy eager load the relation afterwards but with no luck.

Finally I noticed that if I request all the Telephone models fields, the relation will eager load as I request. For example:

```
$myTelephones = Telephone::with('directorate')

                ->haveNoEmployeeId()

                ->where('directorate_id', $directorateId)

                ->get();
```

Then as a result:

```
[
{
"id": 79,
"tel": "0648136867",
"directorate": {
                "id": 23
                 "name": "Some name"
                }    
},
{
"id": 380,
"tel": "0223796011",
"directorate": {
                "id": 23
                 "name": "Some name"
                }       
}  
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after digging into Laravel's details for a while, I noticed that my initial question was out of context and somewhat silly. I was first eager loaded a relationship and then fatuously I filtered out the relationship by not including it in get() parameters. I had just to do the following:

```
$myTelephones = Telephone::with('directorate')

                ->haveNoEmployeeId()

                ->where('directorate_id', $directorateId)

                ->get(['id', 'tel', 'description', 'directorate']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your telephone does not have any relationship with the directorate model.
put this in your Telephone model.

```
public function directorate()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Directorate::class);
}
```

Comment: it's a typo I had acctually the relationship in my model and the problem is still there. I corrected my post accordingly